# Popup DatePicker using DialogFragment and saving selection to TextView or EditText

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar, popup

I'm writing this partially as a guide as complete newcomer, and partially to ask about best practice.  After some time trying to implement the above question, and finding guides mainly for DatePickerDialogs with the now void showDialog method I finally pieced together a workable solution, but most other answers to similar assume a great deal of previous knowledge.

I used: a new DatePickerFragment.java class, an Activity java class, and a XML layout.

The aim was to have a TextView showing the current date plus one week, with a button next to it that would pop up a calendar to select a new date, that would populate both the TextView with a string date, and a hidden view with that date as a long.

I ended up with the below code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Set current date to default date in date picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), 
(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity(),
            year, month, day);
   }
}
```

This is slightly different from the official use listed here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Instead of the `implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` being in DatePickerFragment I put it in the below NewTaskActivity:

```
public class NewTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
private TextView text_date_picker;
private TextView text_date_picker_hidden;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_task);

    text_date_picker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_date_picker);
    text_date_picker_hidden = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_date_picker_hidden);

//get current date to set as default displayed date
    long datemilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (86400 * 7 * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date resultdate = new Date(datemilliseconds);
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(resultdate);
// set default date to one week after todays date
    text_date_picker.setText(formattedDate);
    text_date_picker_hidden.setText(String.valueOf(datemilliseconds));
}
//when pressed the button creates the pop up calendar
public void onNewTaskDateClick(View view){
    DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
    picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
//the date selected on the calendar changes the text stored in the TextView
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, day);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

    text_date_picker.setText(formattedDate);
    text_date_picker_hidden.setText(String.valueOf(c.getTimeInMillis()));
}
```

The XML layout snippet of these actions looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_date_picker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_date_picker_hidden"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_choose_task_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onNewTaskDateClick"
                android:text="Change Exipry Date" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure if it was best practice to change where the `implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` is, and am brand new  to Android, so may have made errors in other places!  Feel free to let me know, or to use this as a guide.